# Perl hashes: assign value to a key and see if the key was defined

Tags: perl, hashmap

Is there an efficient way to see, if a hash key assignment resulted in adding a new item or in modifying an existing one? Something similar in behavior to the `add` function in this [Bloom's filter implementation](http://search.cpan.org/~palvaro/Bloom-Faster-1.6/lib/Bloom/Faster.pm).

In the construct below two lookups are performed: once explicitly with `exists` and another time implicitly during the assignment. The first lookup is thus logically redundant.

```
my %hash;
my $key;
...
my $existed = exists $hash{$key};
$hash{$key} = 1;
```

Comment: FYI, you should use [`exists`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exists.html) to check if a hash key exists, not `defined`. Out of curiosity, what do you need this for?

Comment: `defined` was there by design: in my particular case the values if exist are always defined. This is for duplicate filtering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "item", I think you mean "key".

If the value is meaningless, you can use the following:

```
my $dup = $hash{$key}++;
```

If the value is meaningful, you can use the following:

```
my $dup = exists($hash{$key});
$hash{$key} = $val;
```

If the value is meaningful but always defined, you can use the following:

```
my $ref = \$hash{$key};
my $dup = defined($$ref);
$$ref = $val;
```

---

By the way, the first snippet can easily be extended to filter out duplicates from a list.

```
my %seen;
my @unique = grep !$seen{$_}++, @list;
```

Comment: Great! Stupid me, I didn't realize an increment for an uninitialized key is eligible. Do you have any reference for your idea that hash lookups are cached?

Comment: Nope, removing that bit.

Comment: By the way, correct me if I'm wrong, but if there is no caching, your second solution (identical now with mine) invokes two lookups.

Comment: Yes. But lookups are rather fast, and the speed stays the same no matter how many elements you have in the hash (O(1)).

Comment: A minibenchmark shows, that the `++` solution is much faster than the two lookups solution, which in turn is faster than the reference solution. There doesn't seem to be any caching.